# Changing the interval on timers in c#

Tags: c#, timer, type-conversion

I'm trying to change the interval on a timer when I click a button, but the problem I'm having is the timer's interval is an int, and I want to multiply it by 0.9. I tried casting the interval as a float, but got no luck there. Any help would be great, thank you.

My code:

```
 private void Upgrade_Buildings(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

Irrelevant code...

```
            (float) TimeOreCounter.Interval *= 0.9f;
            UpdateResources();
```

More Irrelevant Code...

```
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the conversion on the right hand side, then cast back for assignment:

```
TimeOreCounter.Interval = (int)(TimeOreCounter.Interval * 0.9);
```

Note that multiplying an `int * double` will automatically promote the integer to a double, so there isn't a cast required there, but the cast is required to set back to the integer property.